# AngularJS/MVC Routing - Tried to Load Angular More Than Once

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

yes there are multiple questions similar to mine but I cant find a solution in any of them

I have a base page on the Controller/Action Home/Index

I want to use this as the basis for my SPA but cant get the routing to full work, my route **config is:**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: '/Home/Location.cshtml',
      controller: 'myCtrl'
    });
});
```

There is a View and Action that does follow that routing, I am 100% certain of but if I keep '.cshtml' within the route config I get a 404 error but if I remove it I get 'Tried to Load Angular More Than Once'

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularjs")
  .Include("~/Scripts/angular.js")
  .Include("~/Scripts/PortalController/PortalController.js")
  .Include("~/Scripts/angular-route.js")
  .Include("~/Scripts/PortalController/PortalController.config.js"));

ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<div class="card text-center mb-3">
  < div class="card-header">
    <h1 class="display-1"> Search Stock Location </h1>
    <hr/>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <p class="card-text"> Enter the SKU(Product code) or Seach by product name
  </p>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbSearchBar" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primaru"> Search
</button>
</div>
```

Any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have the reference of angularjs on `Index.cshtml`. Please remove reference from either your `cshtml` page or from the bundle.

Comment: added my entire index.cshtml file to the post

Comment: You are using some other js like PortalControler.js . Please check if angularjs reference exists in any of other js. It should be remove